# Is there any way to ask permission after denied in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to get permission alert again after denies that permission before in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has previously denied access, you can present an alert with a description of why it is essential for correct operation of the app with a button that will open [`openSettingsURLString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623042-opensettingsurlstring). If they select the option to open settings, you can open it with [`open(_:options:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open).

But you should do this only if it’s truly required for successful operation (e.g., don’t nag them about location info just because you want that info, but only if the app cannot function as desired by the user in the absence of their permission).

Answer (score 1):

No, you get one shot at this. Afterwards, the user must go into Settings to change their choice. This is why it is very important to be careful about when and how you ask permission. In many cases apps "pre-flight" permission by presenting custom UI that explains what you're asking for, why, and what the user must do, before presenting the actual system dialog only if the user has already indicated that they want to grant permission.

Remember that the user can also revoke permission after they've granted it, and the app needs to recover gracefully in that case. If you require permission in order to function, then you'll need to include UI to guide the user to the settings app and explain to them how to configure the system. Again, you'll want to carefully explan what you're asking for and why you need it.

See [Requesting Permission](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/) for additional best practices.